# Enable VoiceOver on the view and it subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, subview, voiceover

**Background**: Like the voicemail view inside Apple's Phone app. I want to be able to get voiceover announcement from the cell context as well as the individual controls.

**Problem**: It seems that if the parent view has the accessibility turned on, the subviews become non-accessible.

I looked into `shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren` and `accessibilityViewIsModal` but they don't seem to solve it. I think `UIAccessibilityNavigationStyle` might be the answer but not sure how to use it.

---

**Clarification**: This has nothing to do with visual voicemail. Below shows the picture of the Apple's native app with voice over on. The black box is where the target of the voice is. The green box just blocks out some private info.

When select the overall box
[image]

When select the play button 
[image]

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the question without referring to visual voicemail as visual voicemail is not available in all countries (like mine)? Either please find a different example or preferably describe your specific UI and actual/expected behavior in full detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into subclassing the `UIAccessibilityContainer` protocol.  I believe this is what you want.  Create a custom accessibility container that is the parent for all of the things that you want.  You then have more fine grained control over how your super view, and it's children, get reported to the accessibility APIs.

Comment: I should probably have updated it but I came to the same conclusion. However, you can also just pretty much add a subview the size of the parent view and make that accessible. It will allow you to move around as if you use the container without having to go into the nitty gritty.

Comment: Any thoughts on this use case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538359/ios-accessibility-make-uitextfield-and-specified-subview-accessible