# MKAnnotationView custom callout is invisible to Accessibility (VoiceOver)

Tags: ios, accessibility, mapkit, mkmapview, voiceover

I have a `MKAnnotationView` subclass and place several of them on an `MKMapView`. The `MKAnnotationView` subclass sets some accessibility elements like this:

```
func applyAccessibility() {
    
    self.isAccessibilityElement = true
    self.accessibilityTraits = [.none]
    
    self.accessibilityLabel = "Bus stop map pin"
    self.accessibilityValue = busStop.name
}
```

VoiceOver reads out the names of the bus stops that are pinned on the map.

I then use a `UIView` subclass as the callout view when a bus stop is tapped.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    
    if let annotation = view.annotation
    {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation
        {
            // This is our location marker
            return
        }
        
        busStopAnnotationCalloutView.setupForAnnotationView(view, delegate: self)
        
        view.addSubview(busStopAnnotationCalloutView)
        
        mapView.setCenter(annotation.coordinate, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This works great, however this callout view is totally invisible to VoiceOver.

In the `init` of the callout view I set:

```
isAccessibilityElement = true
accessibilityTraits = .none
accessibilityLabel = "Callout view"
accessibilityIdentifier = "BusStopAnnotationCalloutView.callout"
```

and it also creates it's own labels and a button of which I set similar like this:

```
label.isAccessibilityElement = true
label.accessibilityTraits = .header
label.accessibilityLabel = "\(busStop.name)"
```

UIButton

```
button.isAccessibilityElement = true
button.accessibilityTraits = .button
button.accessibilityLabel = "Select this bus stop"
```

but none of these elements are visible to VoiceOver. The `Accessibility Inspector` can't see them.

As I move around the view with the `Accessibility Inspector` it just picks up and `MKAnnotation`'s that are on the map underneath the callout.

EDIT --------

I have created a small example project that has a custom callout view that just won't get any accessibility.

[Example project](http://venderbase.com/Map%20Test.zip)

And there's also a short screen recording showing the problem:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3X02GTzXdo)

Comment: I Can't download your example but I can reproduce the problem with my project. Did you try to use an `UIAccessibilityContainer`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538359/ios-accessibility-make-view-and-subview-accessible (Still on my todo list, sorry)

Comment: No, that question doesn't really explain it, but i'll do some research on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that your callout view is a child of your annotation view.
Therefore if your annotation view has it's `isAccessibilityElement` set to true you can not focus on the callout.
A way of solving this is setting the `isAccessibilityElement` of your annotation to false each time it is selected and vice versa.

Comment: Wow! You are correct. Even Apple didn't pick up on this through both DTS and Bug Report. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After going directly to Apple with a `Developer Technical Support` request, they suggested it is a bug, however as this doesn't work on any version of iOS that I tested, i'd suggest it is more an oversight than a bug and i'm surprised no-one else has wanted to make a map view callout accessible.

Apple DTS also asked if I wanted them to look for a workaround and after a few days they came back to say there simply isn't one!

So for now, as of iOS 12.4, the answer here is that it's just not possible.